# Replace HTML link with Javascript link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I would like to change URL link of one of buttons in my navbar of my site to a javascript link.

The following is what I have now:

```
`<a href='http://www.oldlink.com' rel='nofollow' class='deals' target='_blank'>&nbsp;</a>`
```

I would like to replace `http://www.oldlink.com` with:

```
<script>this is the snippet for the new link</script>
```

Can anyone please show me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Your script is just a bunch of text, that's not Javascript.

Comment: You could always use `javascript:`, but it's almost never a good idea.  What is it that you're trying to do?  Add a click handler?

Comment: BTW, you end a script tag with `</script>`, not `</noscript>`

Comment: @barmar I didn't want to post the actual javascript text. <script>this is the snippet for the new link</noscript> represents that javascript code

Comment: @Brad I am trying link an ebay affiliate link to one of the buttons on my nav bar. The code snippet that ebay gave my is in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Javascript when the user clicks on the link, do:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="some_javascript_function();" ...>

<script>
function some_javascript_function() {
    // Do what you want
}
</script>
```

Comment: what would I put here "some_javascript_function();"? Sorry I do not know much about coding

Comment: Sorry, but if you want to participate here, you really should be a programmer. We can help you solve problems in your programs, but we're not a tutoring service. Give your function a meaningful name, and put that in place of `some_javascript_function`

Comment: Is `href="javascript:void(0)"` still acceptable? I don't see many of those anymore.

Comment: @Rudie Yes, it's fine AFAIK. You can also put `#` in the `href`. Then you should call `event.preventDefault()` in the `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x23kj09m/1/)

```
function changelink() {

    // old value
    a = document.querySelector('a').href

    alert(a)

    // now changing value
    b = document.querySelector('a').href = "www.google.com"

    // changed value
    alert(b)
}
```